# Creating a WiFi Access Point with a New IP Space

Tags: networking, wifi, local-area-network, repeater

I just moved into a dorm where each room gets a limited range of IP addresses to connect their devices to. For the sake of comfort (I don’t want to assign fixed IP addresses to each of my devices), I would like to set up some kind of switch or repeater that I can connect to with an automatic IP.

I’ve already tested it with the “Create Hotspot” function in Windows 10 and it works perfectly. Now I need some advice on which physical device can create that behaviour and how to set it up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done by almost any accesspoint with routing capabilitys (which are probably >90% of all devices from the consumer market).

There are two fundamental ways of connecting such networks: bridging and routing (usually with NAT). Since you want to use DHCP (dynamic assignment of IP adresses) in your WiFi, you want to use the AP as router with NAT - with a static IP assigned on it's "WAN" port.